# Как отсортировать поддиректории по дате создания c#

Tags: c#, сортировка, дата

Я разобрался как сортировать файлы в папке, теперь возник вопрос как нужно модифицировать эту строку чтобы я мог получить отсортированный массив путей под дириктории

```
string[] fileArry = Directory.GetFiles(pathgfile).OrderBy(d => new FileInfo(d).CreationTime).ToArray();

string[] dirArry=Directory.GetDirectories(pathdir);
```

Comment: Что мешает сделать тоже? Только не FileInfo, а DirectoryInfo.

Comment: string [] dir= Directory.GetDirectories(path).OrderBy(d => new DirectoryInfo(d).CreationTime).ToArray();        выдаёт ошибку "System.IO.IOException: Неверно задано имя папки."

Comment: ну дак вы вместо path введите имя директрии, например "C:\\"

Comment: я вставил свой верный путь

Comment: И какой у вас "верный путь" ?

Comment: string pathDoc = UserPath + "\\" + (message.From.Id) + @"\Documents\";

Comment: он работает в Directory.GetDirectories

Comment: А вы уже сформированный путь, который у вас в `pathDoc` показать можете? Ибо ваш код и код из ответа лично у меня нормально работает. Да и ошибка вам явно говорит, что путь вы указываете не правильный!

Comment: C:\bot\Telegram Bot data\user data\199205863\Documents\Your Virtual Support

Comment: И он существует? В проводнике вы можете туда попасть?

Comment: да , немного ошибся он выглядит вот так C:\bot\Telegram Bot data\user data\199205863\Documents\   и оно замечательно работает с  простым методом

Comment: Всё решил проблему, благодарю запомнишь, ошибка была из-за разницы в названии переменных в последовательных методах

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var directories = Directory.GetDirectories("path")
                                   .ToDictionary(x => x, x => Directory.GetCreationTime(x))
                                   .OrderBy(x => x.Value);
```

Comment: каким типом будет являться var? И если это не массив как его переписать в него

Comment: Dictionary<string,DateTime>, конечно можно и в массив  var directories = Directory.GetDirectories("C:\\")
                                       .ToDictionary(x => x, x => Directory.GetCreationTime(x))
                                       .OrderBy(x => x.Value).Select(x=>x.Key).ToArray();

Comment: В данном случае это неявно типизированная локальная переменная, компилятор пытается вычислить тип на основе контекста. Но тут есть момент в виде явного преобразования к типу Dictionary используя linq.

Comment: выдаёт ошибку System.IO.IOException: Неверно задано имя папки." Мне нужно получить массив для дальнейшего обращения к нему в зависимости от заданного индекса

Comment: Код в коментарии возвращает массив)) Покажите какую директорию вы указали, может быть вы не добавили экранивароние для \?

Comment: string pathDoc = UserPath + "\\" + (message.From.Id) + @"\Documents\";  UserPath это путь до корневой папки программы

Comment: Нет, вы покажите что "в итоге" попадает в путь, не переменные

Comment: этот путь работает в dirArry=Directory.GetDirectories()

Comment: Еще раз, просто скиньте итоговое значение, которое подставляете

Comment: чистый вид C:\bot\Telegram Bot data\user data\199205863\Documents\Your Virtual Support

Comment: я использовал код который предложили вы и заменил в нем путь

Comment: Ну давайте ради интереса вставьте туда "C:\\" и скажите что будет

Comment: string[] dokArry = Directory.GetDirectories(@"C:\bot\Telegram Bot data\user data\199205863\Documents\") .ToDictionary(x => x, x => Directory.GetCreationTime(x)) .OrderBy(x => x.Value).Select(x=>x.Key).ToArray();

Comment: Работает, но что тогда не так в моём пути ?

Comment: К сожалению дистанционно не могу сказать(

Comment: Из проводника у вас конкретно этот путь открывается?

Comment: Всё решил проблему, благодарю запомнишь, ошибка была из-за разницы в названии переменных в последовательных методах

Comment: Ещё раз извиняюсь, а как изменить-Сейчас самый старый сверху, что изменить чтобы стало наоборот