# Что изменить в запросе чтобы сортировка была наоборот?

Tags: c#, сортировка, linq

Я совсем недавно в более-менее живом программировании.

Я в [другом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/823319/176064) получил строку

```
Directory.GetDirectories(@pathDoc)
         .ToDictionary(
            x => x, 
            x => Directory.GetCreationTime(x))
         .OrderBy(x => x.Value)
         .Select(x => x.Key)
         .ToArray();`
```

она работает.

Что нужно изменить, чтобы сортировка была в обратную сторону?
Сейчас в массиве самый старый наверху, как сделать наоборот?

Comment: `OrderBy` => `OrderByDescending`

Comment: У вас две лишних материализации в запросе, я бы переписал его так: `Directory.EnumerateDirectories(pathDoc).OrderBy(x => Directory.GetCreationTime(x)).ToArray()`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Попробуйте `OrderByDescending`, вместо `OrderBy`

Т.е.:

```
Directory.GetDirectories(@pathDoc)
         .ToDictionary(x => x, x => Directory.GetCreationTime(x))
         .OrderByDescending(x => x.Value)
         .Select(x => x.Key)
         .ToArray();
```